# URL rewrite in .htaccess file

Tags: apache, url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two problems in my current .htaccess. The script below works but has a limitation

```
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9])$ /products/$1/ [R]
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9])/$ /viewad.php?adid=$1
```

**Limitation:** if adid, is more than 10. it fails. I want it to have whatever number still there and work. my current solution was to add this everytime the id went higher than range.

```
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9][0-9])$ /products/$1/ [R]
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9][0-9])/$ /viewad.php?adid=$1
```

Could some one refine or explain how to correct this rule to take numbers out of range.

**Problem Two.**
  Mapping multiple $_GET variables.

say i had a url like this

```
http://veepiz.com/africanews.php?app=view&func=viewcategory&categoryid=2&page=1
```

what rule would i write to have it in this format.

```
http://veepiz.com/africanews/category/2/page/1
```

or

```
http://veepiz.com/africanews/2/1
```

Thanx a lot for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First problem:**

```
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)$ /products/$1/ [R]
RewriteRule ^products/([0-9]+)/$ /viewad.php?adid=$1
```

Or better yet:

```
RewriteRule ^products/(\d+)/?$ /viewad.php?adid=$1
```

**Problem Two:**

```
RewriteRule ^africanews/(\d+)/(\d+)$ /africanews.php?app=view&func=viewcategory&categoryid=$1&page=$2
```

Comment: thanx alot aularon. Any one have an answer for problem 2?

Comment: okay, the rule fails when i have a link witha trailing slash for problem 2. i have done this but it fails RewriteRule ^africanews/(\d+)/(\d+)$ /africanews/$1/$2/ [R]

Answer (score 0):

This fixes problem 2 (thanks to aularon):

```
RewriteRule ^africanews/(\d+)/(\d+)$ /africanews/$1/$2/ [R]
RewriteRule ^africanews/(\d+)/(\d+)/$ /africanews.php?app=view&func=viewcategory&categoryid=$1&page=$2
```