# htaccess file ( url rewriting )

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is possibile convert this url:

http://corpovigiligiuratife.it/promo.php

to

http://corpovigiligiuratife.it/promozione-porta-un-amico

with htaccess MOD Rewrite?

I did several searches but I could not figure out how to convert this url.

I have 2 static 2 url and not a dynamic url.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewrite in .htaccess file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653320/url-rewrite-in-htaccess-file)

Answer (score -1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^promozione-porta-un-amico$ promo.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this as the content of the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^promo.php$ promozione-porta-un-amico [R=301]
```

It will **redirect** the user from `promo.php` to `promozione-porta-un-amico`

The `R=301` means that this link is **Moved Permanently**.

Comment: That isn't what the question asks.